# How i can get the arguments of my Json and validate before of make a post int web api 2 .net?

Tags: c#, .net, json

For example, the next json, I want validate the amount before of make a post

```
{
    "amount":"10"
}
```

Could I create a filter class and get this argument and validate it, I have to make a cast?

```
public class ValidateModelTransaction : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var posted = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        TransactionModel amount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionModel>(posted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give us a bit more context? Where/how are you going to use this validation? An ASP.NET application, or...?

Comment: ASP.NET web api 2, I have a transactionController class that has a method to make the publication, but before should going through the filter to validate the quantity parameter.

Comment: namespace SchoolPortal.API.Filters
{
    public class ValidateModelTransaction : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
       

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        { 
            var posted = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            TransactionModel amount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionModel>(posted);


        }

Comment: Please edit your question and add all these details

Comment: Added more details to my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Hi, the next code line 
            var json = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; //is null

Comment: Well, find a way to read the json string of the request object - after that you just need to invoke my method :)

Comment: could use  var values = actionContext.ActionArguments.Values;

Comment: Run some tests and try to find a way to read the json. I have tested my method but not the ValidateModelTransaction attribute. I cannot do everything for you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function that uses a `JsonTextReader` to read the value of the `amount` property, and takes a delegate as a parameter to validate the amount:

```
private static bool ValidateAmount(string json, Func<int, bool> validateFunc)
{
    using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)))
    {
        reader.CloseInput = true;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && reader.Value.Equals("amount"))
            {
                int? amount = reader.ReadAsInt32();

                if (!amount.HasValue)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                bool isValid = validateFunc(amount.Value);
                return isValid;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Using a delegate as a parameter (`Func<int, bool> validateFunc`) allows you to reuse the method in different scenarios - example:

```
string json = @"{""amount"":""10""}";

bool isPositiveAmount = ValidateAmount(json, x => x > 0); // returns true
bool isBetween100And200 = ValidateAmount(json, x => x > 100 && x < 200); // returns false
```

## EDIT

The `ValidateAmount` method can eventually be used in an `ActionFilterAttribute`.

Example - check if the amount is positive:

```
public class ValidateModelTransaction : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var json = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        bool isPositiveAmount = ValidateAmount(json, x => x > 0);

        if (isPositiveAmount)
        {
            // ....
        }
    }
}
```